# How to use bash return code in conditional?

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements, return-value

I have a small piece of code which checks IP address validity :

```
function valid_ip()
{
    local  ip=$1
    local  stat=1

    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        if [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
            && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]; then
            stat=1
        else
            stat=0
        fi
    fi
    return $stat
}
```

But I am having problems with its usage in bash conditionals. I have tried many techniques to test its return value but most of them fail on me.

```
if [[ !$(valid_ip $IP) ]]; then

if [[ $(valid_ip IP) -eq 1 ]]; then
```

etc. etc. Can anyone suggest what should I do here ?

**EDIT**

Following your suggestions I have used something like :

```
  if valid_ip "$IP" ; then
      ... do stuff
  else
      perr "IP: \"$IP\" is not a valid IP address"
  fi
```

and I get errors like

> IP: "10.9.205.228" is not a valid IP address

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The return code is available in the special parameter `$?` after the command exits. Typically, you only need to use it when you want to save its value before running another command:

```
valid_ip "$IP1"
status1=$?
valid_ip "$IP2"
if [ $status1 -eq 0 ] || [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

or if you need to distinguish between various non-zero statuses:

```
valid_ip "$IP"
case $? in
    1) echo valid_IP failed because of foo ;;
    2) echo valid_IP failed because of bar ;;
    0) echo Success ;;
esac
```

Otherwise, you let the various operators check it implicitly:

```
if valid_ip "$IP"; then
    echo "OK"
fi

valid_IP "$IP" && echo "OK"
```

---

Here is a simple, idiomatic way of writing `valid_ip`:

```
valid_ip () {
    local ip=$1
    [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]] && {
        IFS='.' read a b c d <<< "$ip"
        (( a < 255 && b < 255 && c < 255 && d << 255 ))
    }
}
```

There are two expressions, the `[[...]]` and the `{ ... }`; the two are joined by `&&`. If the first fails, then `valid_ip` fails. If it suceeds, then the second expression (the compound statement) is evaluated. The `read` splits the string into four variables, and each is tested separately inside the arithmetic expression. If all are true, then the `((...))` succeeds, which means the `&&` list succeeds, which means that `valid_ip` succeeds. No need to store or return explicit return codes.

Comment: The shell interprets 0 as success and non-zero as failure, opposite of the usual Boolean interpretation. `valid_IP` should return 0 if the IP address is valid, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: No. That's a problem with set -e not with this.

Answer (score 17):

No parentheses needed if the exit status is inspected:

```
if valid_ip $IP ; then
    ...
```

Just call the function in the way you would call any other command.

Comment: @Patryk: Note that commands return 0 on success. Return 0 for a valid IP.

Comment: But I thought `${ip[0]} -le 255` is to check that first octet is less than or equal to 255 and so on for remaining octets.

Comment: @Patryk: No problem with that. Just switch `stat=0` and `stat=1`.