# How to get the exit code when running `if ! command; then`?

Tags: shell, if-statement, command-line, error-handling

When I want to take action on a failure I do:

```shell
if ! commmand; 
then
    echo $?
fi
```

But the exit code is always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to exit status later, you might consider saving it in a variable:

```sh
command
status=$?
if (( status != 0 )); then
    echo $status
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the `!` negation and using an empty `then` block:

```shell
if commmand; 
then :
else
    echo $?
fi
```

Related questions:

1. [Bash conditional based on exit code of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command)
2. [Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code/90435)
3. [How to use bash return code in conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573312/how-to-use-bash-return-code-in-conditional)